# URL Name not resolved in Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, image

I am trying to dynamically build up HTML using JQuery in ASP.NET MVC5. I have so far had success, but the URL cannot be resolved in the JQuery Code.

My code looks something like this:

```
$.ajax({
  type: 'POST',
  url: '@Url.Action("QuerySearch")',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
    queryName: $("#queryText").val()
  },
  success: function (data) {
    // var items = '';
    $.each(data, function (i, item) {

    var resource_Url = item.ResourceURL;
    // var resource_url = item.ResourceURL;
    var append_data = $('<div class="row">'
    + '<h3>' + item.ResourceTitle + '</h3>'
    + '</div>'
    + '<div class="row">'
    + '<span class="label label-primary" style="margin:3px;font-size:small;">'
    + item.ResourceEducation
    + '</span>'
    + '<span class="label label-warning" style="margin:3px;font-size:small;">'
    + item.ResourceGrades
    + '</span>'
    + '<span class="label label-info" style="margin:3px;font-size:small;">'
    + item.ResourceSubject
    + '</span>'

    + '<a href="@Url.Content("' + item.ResourceURL + '")">'
    + '<img src="@Url.Content("~/Content/Resources/download_icon.png")" alt="Download Resource" style="height:24px;width:24px;"/>' 
    + '</a>'
```

Although this code is able to retrieve the image for the download_icon defined in my project, it is not able to display / embed the URL fetched from the server by my function which I am trying to display in the `<a href>` tag.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: `@Url.Content()` is razor code which is executed on the server before its sent to the view. `item` is a javascript variable that does not even exist at that point - its not in scope. Either have you method return a partial view or build you `<a>` element manually without `@Url.Content(("' + item.ResourceURL + '")`

Answer (score 2):

You will need to pass the complete url value from the server as a property of the data received. Or have it stored locally

ASP code doesn't run in the browser, only on server

Comment: I didn't understand. My function correctly retrieves the values item.ResourceEducation, item.ResourceGrades and item.ResourceTitle. It's also able to retrieve the URL using item.ResourceURL. But I can't get it to embed inside the @Url.Content() function. Moreover, a blank url also works.

Comment: You are trying to pass a javascript variable to a server side function. You can't do that. They run in completely different environments at different times

Comment: Ah, I see. How do I do it otherwise?

Comment: you have to send the complete appropriate url from server and get rid of `@Url.Content()`. The other works because you are passing a valid server side argument to the function

Comment: I'll try and figure out how I can do that. Thanks for the help :) much appreciated. If you find time, please provide me with the code. I would be willing to provide more info.

Comment: well you already know what `item.ResourceURL` is in the back end.. compile it there

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125450/discussion-between-aditya-and-charlietfl).

Answer (score 0):

The trick was simple, the href tag had to be changed to:

```
'<a href="' + item.ResourceURL + '">'
```

It worked like a charm